# Want to not see closed issues in Redmine Roadmap

Tags: redmine

I can't seem to find a way set my project's Redmine Roadmap to *not* show closed issues. I just want to see open issues. Sure, I can click the "open" link and go right to the Issues tab, but then I lose the other Roadmap goodness.

Is there a way to configure Redmine to *not* show closed issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your closed issues show up as grayed text with strike-through lines on the issue numbers?  I ask because I want to know whether you are annoyed by the fact that those closed issues are not show up as closed, or you are annoyed by their mere existence.

Comment: Yes, my closed issues show up gray with the strike-though. I am annoyed by their existence. I want to see only open issues in my roadmap. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way might be to hide it with jQuery. Add this to your theme javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.closed").parent().parent().hide();
});
```

(Tested in `Redmine 2.1.2.stable.10610`. YMMV.)

Comment: Also works with the View Customize plugin using the "/roadmap" filter.